# Return an element in array if condition is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given this array:

```
[[{"RepCode"=>"AL20", "ID"=>"eae71dff-3796-4c61-956e-a75a00b01a7b", "Name"=>"Schuh, Eddy", "Folios"=>[]}],
[{"RepCode"=>"ABNX", "ID"=>"637e9117-ed03-45ef-8950-a7220087ee9a", "Name"=>"Eckerson, Kathy", "Folios" => [{"ID"=>"d0cda2be-c142-47d1-9a81-a76c0eea2765"}],
[{"RepCode"=>"ABCD", "ID"=>"637e9117-ed03-45ef-8950-a234902038", "Name"=>"Sarah, Barber", "Folios" => [{"ID"=>"46aafe31-f686-49e2-9d58-c694ea55c14f"}]]
```

I need to return the **ONE** array that matches the given id for the `Folio` key

#### CODE:

```
correct_manager = managers.detect do |manager|
  manager.first["Folios"].map { |f| f["ID"] == "d0cda2be-c142-47d1-9a81-a76c0eea2765" }
end
```

That returns:

```
{"RepCode"=>"AL20", "ID"=>"eae71dff-3796-4c61-956e-a75a00b01a7b", "Name"=>"Schuh, Eddy", "Folios"=>[]}
```

And I want it to return

```
{"RepCode"=>"ABNX", "ID"=>"637e9117-ed03-45ef-8950-a7220087ee9a", "Name"=>"Eckerson, Kathy", "Folios" => [{"ID"=>"d0cda2be-c142-47d1-9a81-a76c0eea2765"}
```

because the ID's match in the detect method.

How can I return the one array that matches the passed in id?

Comment: Your array seems to be bad formatted.

Comment: Do the `Folios` arrays ever contain more than one Folio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Enumerable [#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

```
correct_manager = managers.find do |manager|
  folios = manager.first["Folios"][0] || {}
  folios["ID"] == "d0cda2be-c142-47d1-9a81-a76c0eea2765"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def doit(managers, val)
  managers.find { |(h)| h["Folios"] == ["ID"=>val] }
end

managers = [
  [{ "RepCode"=>"AL20", "Folios"=>[] }],
  [{ "RepCode"=>"ABNX", "Folios"=>[{ "ID"=>"d0cda2be-c142-47d1-9a81" }] }],
  [{ "RepCode"=>"ABCD", "Folios"=>[{ "ID"=>"46aafe31-f686-49e2-9d58" }] }]
]

doit(managers, "d0cda2be-c142-47d1-9a81")
  # => [{"RepCode"=>"ABNX", "Folios"=>[{"ID"=>"d0cda2be-c142-47d1-9a81"}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

First let's format your data correctly:

```
managers =  [
  [ {"RepCode"=>"AL20", "ID"=>"eae71dff-3796-4c61-956e-a75a00b01a7b", "Name"=>"Schuh, Eddy", "Folios"=>[] } ],
  [ {"RepCode"=>"ABNX", "ID"=>"637e9117-ed03-45ef-8950-a7220087ee9a", "Name"=>"Eckerson, Kathy", "Folios" => [{"ID"=>"d0cda2be-c142-47d1-9a81-a76c0eea2765"}] } ],
  [ {"RepCode"=>"ABCD", "ID"=>"637e9117-ed03-45ef-8950-a234902038", "Name"=>"Sarah, Barber", "Folios" => [{"ID"=>"46aafe31-f686-49e2-9d58-c694ea55c14f"}] } ] 
]

target_id = 'd0cda2be-c142-47d1-9a81-a76c0eea2765'

managers.flatten.find{|k,_v| k['Folios'].any?{|f| f.key?('ID') && f['ID'] == target_id}}
```